# Serial data temperature conversion

Tags: hex

I have a device and the user manual has a description of the serial data communication protocol. In the manual is says. Temperature Setpoint 0x31

Write:

```
[00][02][AA][31][D#1][D#2][CS][CS][0D]
[AA]: [00] for SHG, [01] for THG
[D#1][D#2]:0-16000 (Units: 0.01C) For example, 50.00 C would be [13][88].
```

I can not figure out how to convert 13 and 88 to 50.00.

I am not sure if the SHG or THG have anything to do with it. I don't know what those mean.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OH! I figured it out! 1388 in HEX is 5000. That couldn't be more simple. Sorry for the stupid post! I tried so many other things but didn't think of the simplest one...